# MDCBottomNavigationBar how to add target view controllers

Tags: ios, material-components

I am new to material components iOS and would like to use the MDCBottomNavigationBar to navigate between VCs in my swift app.  I have successfully setup the bar and placed it where I need it.  I used the example docs to do so.  However, I cannot figure out how to connect each tab bar item to a view controller?  Are there any examples out there of how to do this, or a resource I may have missed?

Comment: I'm looking for exactly the same!

Comment: maybe this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50342566/switching-view-controllers-using-mdcbottomnavigationbar-on-ios?rq=1